# spring-boot-data-source-decorator with p6spy are not logging insert statements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, p6spy

I am using p6spy to log the sql statements.we are using springboot/hibernate for Java ORM mapping.I see only select statements are getting loggged in spy.log.when insert statemnets are executing in the code I see only commmit is coming in the log but insert statements are not coming.

```
|connection|commit||
|connection|statement | select * from emp_id where id=1234
```

https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator

```
# Register P6LogFactory to log JDBC events
decorator.datasource.p6spy.enable-logging=true
# Use com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.MultiLineFormat instead of com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.SingleLineFormat
decorator.datasource.p6spy.multiline=true
# Use logging for default listeners [slf4j, sysout, file, custom]
decorator.datasource.p6spy.logging=file
# Log file to use (only with logging=file)
decorator.datasource.p6spy.log-file=spy.log
# Class file to use (only with logging=custom). The class must implement com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.FormattedLogger
decorator.datasource.p6spy.custom-appender-class=my.custom.LoggerClass
# Custom log format, if specified com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.CustomLineFormat will be used with this log format
decorator.datasource.p6spy.log-format=
# Use regex pattern to filter log messages. If specified only matched messages will be logged.
decorator.datasource.p6spy.log-filter.pattern=
# Report the effective sql string (with '?' replaced with real values) to tracing systems.
# NOTE this setting does not affect the logging message.
decorator.datasource.p6spy.tracing.include-parameter-values=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it before p6spy configuration:
`System.setProperty("p6spy.config.excludecategories", "info,debug,result")`

Why it works? You probably have batched updates which are excluded from logging by default.
This solution is kinda ugly, but configuration of excludecategories is currently not supported in spring-boot-data-source-decorator.

Comment: wtf man, you were answering this old post at the same time as me!!! what are the probabilities haha

Comment: crazy :P I've had same problem but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you and finally discovered how to fix that.

By default, p6spy excludes some categories from logging: `info,debug,result,resultset,batch`,
through the `spy.properties` config called `excludecategories`.

The INSERTS, at least here, are part of the `batch` category.

In my case I put in the `spy.properties` file the line:

```
excludecategories=
```

and now it prints the INSERTS.

The documentation can be found in: https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html

I couldn't find if this specific property is possible to be set in the `application.properties` file. Looks like it is not supported by `spring-boot-data-source-decorator` at the moment of this writing.

[]s